# Deny all in nginx include conf file is being ignored

Tags: nginx, include

In my website.conf file I have:

```
upstream website_upstream {
    server unix:/data/website/current/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;

server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:9100 default_server;
    listen 1336 default_server;
    listen [::]:1336 default_server ipv6only=on;
server_name website.domain.com page.website.domain.com;
server_name assets.website.domain.com uploads.website.domain.com;

access_log /var/log/nginx/website.log main;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/website.error.log;

client_max_body_size 1g;

# WARNING: This include needs to be above other includes and location blocks
# so the auth request locations aren't hijacked by another location.

include /etc/nginx/private_mode_server_include.conf;

include /etc/nginx/common/maint_page.conf;
include /etc/nginx/common/error_pages.conf;

root /data/github/current/public;
try_files $uri /index.html @website;

location ~ ^/(assets/|static/|favicon-enterprise.ico$) {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}

# apps and service routes go in here.
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/website_includes/*.conf;

location @website_upstream {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://website_upstream;
}

location @website {
    # Require private mode authentication.
    include /etc/nginx/private_mode_location_include.conf;
    try_files $uri /index.html @website_upstream;
}

# Paths to be excluded from private mode.
location ~* ^(/join|/signup_check/.*|/login(/.*)?|/logout|/sessions?
(?!/_auth_request_(bounce|endpoint))(/.*)?|/auth/.*|/saml/.*|/dashboard|/dashboard/logged_out|/password_reset(/.*)?|/u2f/trusted_facets|/suspended|/api/.*|/[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*/[\w\.\-]+/(archive|zipball|tarball)/.*|/[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*\.private(\.actor)?\.(atom|json)|/notifications/beacon/.*\.gif|/stafftools/reports(/.*)?|/site/sha|/status)$ {
auth_request off;
try_files /index.html @website_upstream;
    }
}
```

I also have the file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/website_includes/page.conf which usually contains:

```
location ~ ^/page(/|$) {
    rewrite ^/page/?(.*)$ $http_x_forwarded_proto://page.website.domain.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

I'm trying to deny a certain subnet from accessing a certain part of my website, and to test I initially had

```
location ~ ^/page(/|$) {
    deny 192.168.0.0/16;
    rewrite ^/page/?(.*)$ $http_x_forwarded_proto://page.website.domain.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

but it was being ignored. So i set it to

```
location ~ ^/page(/|$) {
    deny all;
    rewrite ^/page/?(.*)$ $http_x_forwarded_proto://page.website.domain.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

I also tried:

```
location ~ ^/page(/|$) {
    deny all;
}
```

but this is also being ignored. I tried:

```
sudo systemctl reload nginx
sudo nginx -s reload
```

and also

```
sudo service nginx stop
sudo service nginx start
```

to see if it was a config not being picked up, but no joy. Any ideas?

Thanks
Mark

Comment: What is the complete url you are browsing?

Answer (score 0):

`rewrite` takes precedence over `deny`, therefore the rewrite will happen regardless of `deny/allow` directives.

I *believe you could* use flags after rewrite (break or last) but I don't have experience using them, so my solution is less elegant.

Use the [geo module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html) **outside** the server block to set a variable, then use it in your desired location with the `if` directive, that takes precedence over `rewrite`

```
# this happen in your html block
geo $denied_subnet {
    default        0;
    192.168.0.0/16 1;
}

# this is your server block
server {

    location ~ ^/page(/|$) {
        if($denied_subnet) {
           return 403;
        }
        rewrite ^/page/?(.*)$ $http_x_forwarded_proto://page.website.domain.com/$1 permanent;
    }

}
```